# using javascript to create separate pages for messages?

Tags: javascript

Ok this may be a bit of a confusing question. I have the below javascript in my messages.php page which controls which div will show. Each div has a seperate function.

There's message-content-p1 which contains a while loop that gets all the messages and limits it to 20 messages to show, the second is message-content-p2 and so on each one containing the next while loop only ever showing 20 messages in each.

The idea of this javascript is to create the illusion that there are more messages to be shown on page 2, page 3 and so on.

So far the javascript shows each div on the click of 'm_p1' or m_p2' and fades out the current page and fades in the next page. This works fine for that function. the problem i get is  if a user wants to skip a page and go to page 3 or page 5 without going to page 2 or 4 then the script won't work and nothing is faded in or out.

Like wise if the user goes back to page 1 from page 5 the script doesnt work and does not fade out page 5 and fade in page 1.

Is there a way of doing what i have described and if so could someone please show me how.

Thank you.

```
 <script>
    $(".message-content-p2").hide();
    $('.m_p2').click(function () {
        if ($('.message-content-p2').is(":hidden")) {       
      $('.message-content-p1').fadeOut(500);
      $('.message-content-p2').delay(700).fadeIn(500);


        }

      });

    </script>


    <script>
    $(".message-content-p3").hide();
    $('.m_p3').click(function () {
        if ($('.message-content-p3').is(":hidden")) {       
      $('.message-content-p2').fadeOut(500);
      $('.message-content-p3').delay(700).fadeIn(500);


        }

      });

    </script>

    <script>
    $(".message-content-p4").hide();
    $('.m_p4').click(function () {
        if ($('.message-content-p4').is(":hidden")) {       
      $('.message-content-p3').fadeOut(500);
      $('.message-content-p4').delay(700).fadeIn(500);


        }

      });

    </script>

    <script>
    $(".message-content-p5").hide();
    $('.m_p5').click(function () {
        if ($('.message-content-p5').is(":hidden")) {       
      $('.message-content-p4').fadeOut(500);
      $('.message-content-p5').delay(700).fadeIn(500);


        }

      });

    </script>

    <script>
    $(".message-content-p6").hide();
    $('.m_p6').click(function () {
        if ($('.message-content-p6').is(":hidden")) {       
      $('.message-content-p5').fadeOut(500);
      $('.message-content-p6').delay(700).fadeIn(500);


        }

      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks all very manual and not very scalable for any number of pages.

Why would you not just have the same class for each "page", and on the click of whatever control determines which pages to skip to, just fade out all pages and then fade in only the page corresponding to the index value of the control that was clicked?  For example say all you message "pages" have the class `.message-content` and let's say you have a set of buttons all with class `.m`.  Your jQuery could simply look like this:

```
$('.m').click(function() {
    $('.message-content').fadeOut(500);
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.message-content').get(index).delay(700).fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: erm i could do, but sorry i don't understand how it would know which div to fade in or out? at the minute each sperate div that's 'message-content-p1' or 'message-content-p2' has an sql function labeled get_messages1, get_messages2 and so on. could you put this code into a demonstration or explain a bit more please.

Comment: would all the classes be the same but the id's be different?

Comment: @JohnSimmons You have X number of pages and X number of buttons, links or whatever to display those pages. I am assuming button 1 (at index[0] in the collection of buttons) would correspond to page 1 (at index[0] in the collection of pages).  Therefore you only need to know the index of the button pressed to know the index of the page to show.  No 'message-content-1' type of ids would be needed at all in this case.

Comment: @JohnSimmons Just trying to get you thinking along the lines of a more "jQuery" ways of doing things.  What you are currently doing is kind of using 1% of jQuery's power just to show/hide things, whereas the real power in jQuery's DOM manipulation capabilities is being able to operate across collections of DOM nodes.